# Using setJointValueTarget and setPoseTarget have different results

Tags: ros, moveit, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following code works, if the target is defined by Joint Value. But if I define the same point by Pose (as in the comment section), the planning path is different every time I run the code. And some times the robot is not able to find the path...

I am using hydro on UR10, moveit version is 0.5.20. ubuntu 12.04. I get the position and orientation value of 'goal' by using command: `rosrun tf tf_echo base_link ee_link`, when the end effector reach 'joints'.

So basically, 'goal' and 'joints' are the same position. Why `setJointValueTarge` is working while `setPoseTarget` is not?

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "move_group_test");
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();

  moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroup group("manipulator");
  group.setPlannerId("ESTkConfigDefault");

  std::map<std::string, double> joints;
  joints["shoulder_pan_joint"] = 0;
  joints["shoulder_lift_joint"] = -0.5648;
  joints["elbow_joint"] = -1.06;
  joints["wrist_1_joint"] = -1.69;
  joints["wrist_2_joint"] = -1.76;
  joints["wrist_3_joint"] = 8.572;  
  group.setJointValueTarget(joints);
  group.move();

/*
  geometry_msgs::Pose goal;
  goal.position.x = 0.555;
  goal.position.y = 0.146;
  goal.position.z = 1.156;
  goal.orientation.w = 0.991428;
  goal.orientation.x = 0.0085588;
  goal.orientation.y = -0.087665;
  goal.orientation.z = -0.0964952;
  group.setPoseTarget(goal);
  group.move();
  */

}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/235971/using-setjointvaluetarget-and-setposetarget-have-different-results/) by [ami](https://answers.ros.org/users/26850/ami/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-06-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silent07](https://answers.ros.org/users/29087/silent07/) on 2017-01-17**:
I have a similar issue, did you find any answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you only specify the pose of the end-effector, Inverse Kinematics will be invoked to compute joint value targets internally, that satisfy your request.
This might fail and might find different joint solutions each time.
If you are using the default KDL kinematics plugin, it probably helps to switch to TracIK.
See http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/trac_ik_tutorial.html

---

Originally posted by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) with karma: 2950 on 2017-01-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [silent07](https://answers.ros.org/users/29087/silent07/) on 2017-01-18**:
I found out my issue. It was indeed related to kinematics. Sometimes the IK would give me an elbow up solution and other time elbow down solution. This was with Track_IK. I will try filter the IK solutions and then feed it for planning.

**Comment by [silent07](https://answers.ros.org/users/29087/silent07/) on 2017-01-18**:
I tried the whole thing once again. Again setPoseTarget(Pose) generates some crazy trajectories, while setJointValueTarget(Pose) is always good. Both have the IK issue above but the plan they generate for similar IK solutions is very different.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-01-18**:
You could see whether TracIK configured with the *distance* metric would result in more consistent solutions. It would depend on what your seed is, but it could help.